# RSync Command not working in Script but in Shell direct. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: bash, ssh, cron, raspberry-pi, rsync

This is the command I used.

```
rsync -v -h --progress --stats --ignore-existing --remove-source-files --compress /mnt/ramdisk/Cam/* -r -e "sshpass -p 'yî\`ÃÝíä}' ssh -p12345 USER@IP" :/home/USER/RSYNC/ &>> /home/USER/RSYNC/RSync_Cron.log
```

This Code is sometimes running sometimes not.
If I am in the "CLI" it's running. But if I am starting in in a Script file it is only running if I start the Script in the shell (cli) directly but not if I run the script via the System Cron by adding it via crontab -e

With Crontab I am getting Errors like:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [sender=3.2.3]
```

Some other error occurred after starting the Script file direct from Shell.
The command was running till the End and then this error appears.
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1333) [sender=3.2.3]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
I think it's because of the password or other special chars or something like the part with  `USER@IP":/home/USER/` if I change the space between the " and: to no space then it's working sometimes too.

Could someone help me please with what I am doing wrong?

Im new with RSync and this type of operation with it.

My Goal is to Upload the complete Files and Folder Structure under the given DIR and then after uploading the data it should delete the Source files. It is doing what it should do and it Uploads the Data with folders but it's not doing it every time. It I delete a folder on the remote machine it's not uploading again and so on.

My wish is that it doesn't matter what I am doing to files/folders from source or destination that it would Upload all available files and folder again and again.

Some extra for me would be that I could check the source files extra for file lock or other options to check if the source files are complete and finished with uploading from FTP.
Or if there is no special mechanism to use then if the file is 1 or 2 minutes / a few seconds old.

Comment: If something works in the shell but not in cron, it's usually because it depends on an environment variable you set in one of your shell startup scripts like `.profile` or `.bashrc`.

Comment: @Barmar : I think given this concrete command, and the fact that the OP said that the command was not even written directly into crontab, but via a script file, I don't think that it is related to the environment. After all, `rsync` tried to start the transfer.

Comment: Do you really **need** an explicit remote shell (`-e`)? If the rsync demon is running on the remote host, I think this should not be necessary. Aside from this, please post your crontab line (for the safe side). Also, in the script you call from crontab (and which invokes the rsync), put a `echo bash: $BASH_VERSION 1>&2; set -x`,  so that we can see better what's going on.

Comment: @user1934428 It looks like the error is happening in ssh at the protocol level, so something in the environment that ssh looks for is different. I'm not sure what that could be. This might be better asked at [unix.se].

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I'm new in the Stackoverflow universe xP

Comment: I think I got it. It was in another post. It's the user SSH Keyring that's not accessible from the Cron. If I explain it right. I started the Script/Command in Shell without the password. Then it asks to add the SSH Key to trusted store and then it could run with the password directly. But the Script startet from Cron couldn't use that Key. So now my final version is to change the user in the Cron Script to use that script like me directly in Shell. Another way mentioned was to login direct via SSH Keys.

Comment: @H-OS glad you found your answer. Why don't you answer your own question instead of this being lost in the comments? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer